# Need my code to do multiple commands when inputs are pressed

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

Hello all I am back again with another issue concerning a code for my job. The code I have been working on is meant to connect to a IP server where some options are listed and I can control the servo motor through there. The options listed are FORWARD, BACKWARD, STEP, and STOP. Each command makes the servo motor move a certain way but the problem I need help with is I need the edited the code to work with three input switches which when pressed in real time they allow the motor to make turns without the need of pressing any button on the server and so far the code is not working. They work with some LED lights which when the input switches are pressed also light up each input is paired with an output (LED) respectively and I tried to create a marker that when the input is pressed also says on the server that "LED1 is on" for example. Each input corresponds to an INPUT switch and each output corresponds to an LED light. The Pin variable corresponds to the motor. Here is the code in question:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Servo.h>

const char* ssid = "RETProject";
const char* password = "mporfiri";

WiFiServer server(80);

int Pin = 16; // GPIO13
int var = 0;
int D1 = 5;
int D2 = 4;
int D4 = 2;
int D5 = 14;
int D6 = 12;
int D7 = 13;
int temp1 = 0;
int temp2 = 0;
int temp3 = 0;

Servo servoMotor;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  pinMode(D1, INPUT);
  pinMode(D2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D4, INPUT);
  pinMode(D5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D6, INPUT);
  pinMode(D7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin,INPUT);
  //pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  //digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");

  //servoMotor.attach(Pin);

}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  temp1 = digitalRead(D1);
  temp2 = digitalRead(D4);
  temp3 = digitalRead(D6);
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();

  // Match the request
  if(temp1 == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(D2,HIGH);
    servoMotor.attach(Pin);
    servoMotor.write(90);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(D2,LOW);
  }

  if(temp2 == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(D5,HIGH);
    servoMotor.attach(Pin);
    servoMotor.write(-90);
}
  else {
    digitalWrite(D5,LOW);
}

  if(temp3 == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(D7,HIGH);
}
  else{
    digitalWrite(D7,LOW);
}

  int value = LOW;
  while (value = LOW); {
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1)  {
    //digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    value = HIGH;
    servoMotor.attach(Pin);
    servoMotor.write(0);
    delay(1000);

  }
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1)  {
    //digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    value = LOW;
    servoMotor.attach(Pin);
    servoMotor.write(180);
    delay(1000);

  }
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=STP") != -1){
      var = 1;
      while(var < 10){
    //digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    value = LOW;
    servoMotor.attach(Pin);
    servoMotor.write(90);
    delay(200);
    servoMotor.write(-90);
    delay(200);
    var=var+1;
    }
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=STOP") != -1)  {
    //digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    value = LOW;
    servoMotor.detach();
    delay(1000);
  }

// Set ledPin according to the request
//digitalWrite(ledPin, value);

  // Return the response
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");

  client.print("Robot is now: ");

  if(value == HIGH) {
    client.print("Moving Forward");
  } else if(value == LOW) {
    client.print("Moving Backward");
  } else if(request.indexOf("/LED=STP") != -1) {
    client.print("Moving in Step");
  }else {
    client.print("Stopped");
  }

  if(temp1 == HIGH) {
    client.print("Led_1 is on");
  }else if (temp1 == LOW);{
    client.print("Led_1 is off");
  }

  if(temp2 == HIGH) {
    client.print("Led_2 is on");
  }else if (temp2 == LOW);{
    client.print("Led_2 is off");
  }

  if(temp3 == HIGH) {
    client.print("Led_3 is on");
  }else if (temp3 == LOW);{
    client.print("Led_3 is off");
  }

  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON\"\"><button>Move Forward </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=STP\"\"><button>Step </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF\"\"><button>Move Backward </button></a><br />");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=STOP\"\"><button>STOP </button></a><br />");
  client.println("<a href=\"/Temp1=HIGH\"\"><Input>LED_1 ON </Input></a><br />");  
  client.println("<a href=\"/Temp2=HIGH\"\"><Input>LED_2 ON </Input></a><br />");
  client.println("<a href=\"/Temp3=HIGH\"\"><Input>LED_3 ON </Input></a><br />");
  client.println("</html>");

  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
  Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

P.S. I just edited the code to do the turns when the input is pressed for the third input it is supposed to make a random turn (either left or right the machine needs to decide on its own) and I am not sure how to write that in the code.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/

Comment: rewrite your code so that received commands and button presses are separated from actions being performed ... right now you use something like `if received motorON then run motor` and `if buttonPressed then run motor` ............ instead use something like `if received motorON then set flag` and `if buttonPressed then set flag` then take action depending on state of the flag `if flagIsSet then run motor`

Comment: @jsotola how would i write that in the form of code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will only do anything if a client has connected to it because of this line

```
if (!client) {
    return;
  }
```

Your physical button will never do anything on their own unless a client has connected and has sent some data.

For the random direction you use a line like the following to randomly pick a direction

```
int direction = random(0,2) ? 1 : 0 ;
```

your direction variable will be with either 1 or 0 randomly

Comment: `random(0,2) ? 1 : 0` is a convoluted way to write `random(0, 2)`.

Comment: Wow, you're right. hehe.